# Getting undefined method for ActiveRecord::Relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the following models

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :chapters
end
```

and

```
class Chapter < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :book
end
```

in `/chapters/edit/id` I get

```
undefined method `book' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x0000010378d5d0>
```

when i try to access book like this

```
@chapter.book
```

Comment: Can you double check and confirm that `Chapter` has a database column `book_id` and that your database is properly migrated via `rake db:migrate`?

Comment: please show your edit controller method, where @chapter is initialized

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Looks like @chapter is not a single Chapter object. If @chapter is initialized something like this:

```
@chapter = Chapter.where(:id => params[:id])
```

then you get a Relation object (that can be treated as a collection, but not a single object). So to fix this you need to retrieve a record using `find_by_id`, or take a first one from the collection

```
@chapter = Chapter.where(:id => params[:id]).first
```

or

```
@chapter = Chapter.find_by_id(params[:id])
```

Comment: that's strange, so `where` will return a collection even if only one record is returned. appending `first` fixed it.

Comment: @JosephLeBrech if you are finding a single ActiveRecord from an id, you can usually use `@chapter = Chapter.find(params[:id])`

Comment: I'm about to change it so that it does something like `Books.find(params[:book_id]).chapters.where(:chapter_no => params[:chapter_no]).first` because I want the user to be able to reorder the chapters and they have to be accessed that way. so that's i'm changing it not to use find

Comment: Actually here you could simplify a little in order to reduce queries to db, this way: `Chapter.where(:book_id => params[:book_id], :chapter_no => params[:chapter_no]).first`

Comment: In Rails 4, dynamic finders are deprecated.  So, I traded all of my dynamic finders for `.where()`, but then ran into this issue.  Therefore, if you swap out dynamic finders for `.where()`, be sure to also include `.first`.

Comment: In Rails 4 you could also use `.find_by(book_id: params[:book_id], chapter_no: params[:chapter_no])` to get the first record

Answer (score 5):

As the others have said - adding the `.first` method will resolve this. I have experienced this issue when calling a @chapter by it's unique ID. Adding `.first` (or `.take` in Rails 4) will ensure only one object is returned.

Answer (score 4):

Try: `Chapter.find(params[:id]).first`

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar error

```rb
Books.chapters
NoMethodError: undefined method `chapters' for #<Book::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x00007f8f9ce94610>
```

what I needed was:

```rb
Books.includes(:chapters)
```